# TypeError (type '(Route<dynamic>) => bool' is not a subtype of type 'Route<Object>' in type cast) Flutter

Tags: flutter, logout

In flutter, I'm on one Widget and there is logout functionality. So once I click on it I want to remove all other widget's instance from the Widget tree and jump on logout widgets, so what I need to use?

```
TextButton.icon(
  label: const Text('Logout'),
  icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
  onPressed: () {
    Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      ModalRoute.withName(AuthScreens.routeName) as Route<Object>,
      (route) => false,
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `popUntil`

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(AuthScreens.routeName))
```

Or if you are popping and pushing to new page then

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<dynamic>(context, MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(builder: (context)=> NewPage()), ModalRoute.withName(AuthScreens.routeName));
```

Here, `NewPage` represents the page which user to be navigated after logout.(E.g: `RegistrationPage()`)

Comment: Thanks sing sahaab, it's help me.

Answer (score 0):

So I was using wrong approached there. Basically, I was ignoring the it's parameter's Type value, **which should be only Route to String.**

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductListingWidget()),
              (route) => false,
            );
```

with this changes I solved the issue, You can compared my previous code and this code, you will find the proper different in it.